Why am I unable to seed my `DQN` program using`sbx`?
I am trying to seed my DQN program when using sbx but for some reason I keep getting varying results.
Here is an attempt to create a minimal reproducible example -
import gymnasium as gym
import torch
import numpy as np
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
from stable_baselines3.common.monitor import Monitor
import os
import argparse
import random
from sbx import DQN
def run_trials():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--seed', type=int, default=1, help='Random seed for reproducibility. If not provided, a random seed will be generated.')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    # If no seed is provided, generate a random one
    if args.seed is None:
        args.seed = random.randint(1, 1000000)
    print(f"Using seed: {args.seed}")
    # Replace the config loading section with this hardcoded config
    config = {
        "n_timesteps": int(5e4),
        "policy": 'MlpPolicy',
        "learning_rate": 2.3e-3,
        "batch_size": 64,
        "buffer_size": 100000,
        "learning_starts": 1000,
        "gamma": 0.99,
        "target_update_interval": 10,
        "train_freq": 256,
        "gradient_steps": 128,
        "exploration_fraction": 0.16,
        "exploration_final_eps": 0.04,
        "policy_kwargs": dict(net_arch=[256, 256])
    }
    def set_seed(seed):
        """Set seed for reproducibility."""
        os.environ['PYTHONASHSEED'] = str(seed)
        np.random.seed(seed)
        random.seed(seed)
        torch.manual_seed(seed)
        torch.cuda.manual_seed(seed)
        torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True
        torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False

    # Set the seed
    set_seed(args.seed)
    def create_env(seed=None, is_eval=False, initial_states=None):
        # Create the base environment.
        env = gym.make("CartPole-v1")
        env = Monitor(env)

        # Set seeds to ensure deterministic behavior.
        if seed is not None:
            env.observation_space.seed(seed)
            env.action_space.seed(seed)
            env.reset(seed=seed)
        return env
    # Create environments
    env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: create_env(args.seed)])
    policy = config.pop('policy', 'MlpPolicy')
    n_timesteps = config.pop('n_timesteps', int(1e5))  # Use get() with a default value
    # Create the model
    model = DQN(
        policy=policy,
        env=env,
        seed=args.seed,
        **config,
    )
    callback = ([])
    model.learn(total_timesteps=int(n_timesteps // 5), callback=callback,
                reset_num_timesteps=False)

    def create_eval_env(seed=None):
        # Create the base environment for evaluation
        eval_env = gym.make("CartPole-v1")
        # Apply the Monitor wrapper to track episode rewards and statistics
        eval_env = Monitor(eval_env)
        # Set seeds to ensure deterministic behavior
        if seed is not None:
            eval_env.observation_space.seed(seed)
            eval_env.action_space.seed(seed)
            eval_env.reset(seed=seed)
        return eval_env


    def evaluate_model_deterministically(model, seed, num_episodes=100):
        # Create a new environment for evaluation
        eval_env = create_eval_env(seed=seed)
        episode_rewards = []
        for _ in range(num_episodes):
            obs, _ = eval_env.reset()
            done = False
            episode_reward = 0
            while not done:
                action, _ = model.predict(obs, deterministic=True)
                obs, reward, terminated, truncated, _ = eval_env.step(action)
                done = terminated or truncated
                episode_reward += reward
            episode_rewards.append(episode_reward)
        eval_env.close()
        mean_reward = np.mean(episode_rewards)
        std_reward = np.std(episode_rewards)

        return mean_reward, std_reward
    mean_reward, std_reward = evaluate_model_deterministically(model, args.seed)
    return mean_reward, std_reward
mean_rewards = []
std_rewards = []
for run in range(3):
    print("run = ", run)
    mean_reward, std_reward = run_trials()
    mean_rewards.append(mean_reward)
    std_rewards.append(std_reward)

print("mean_rewards = ", mean_rewards)

The results are quite surprising. While running this program multiple-times I get a variety of results.
Here are my results -
Attempt 1:
run =  0
Using seed: 1
run =  1
Using seed: 1
run =  2
Using seed: 1
mean_rewards =  [120.52, 120.52, 120.52]

Attempt 2:
run =  0
Using seed: 1
run =  1
Using seed: 1
run =  2
Using seed: 1
mean_rewards =  [116.64, 116.64, 116.64]

It's surprising that within an attempt, I get the same results. But when I run the program again, I get varying results.
I went over the documentation for seeding the environment from here and also read this - "Completely reproducible results are not guaranteed across PyTorch releases or different platforms. Furthermore, results need not be reproducible between CPU and GPU executions, even when using identical seeds.". However, I would like to make sure that there isn't a bug from my end. Also, I am using sbx instead of stable-baselines3. Perhaps this is a JAX issue?
